# Mapping in .htaacess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, seo

I have a requirement to map an old domain to a different path on a new domain.
Here is what I need to do:

I need a 1 to 1 mapping of this url:
http://www.hikingsanfrancisco.com/san_francisco_hikes/windy_hill_regional_open_space.php

to now go to this url:
http://www.comehike.com/outdoors/parks/park.php?park_id=1

My current .htaccess file looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.comehike.com/$1 [R=301,L]
Redirect /outdoors/trees/tanoak.php http://www.comehike.com/outdoors/trees/129/Tanoak
```

So hopefully the new entry does not break the other ones :)

Thank you,
Alex

Comment: +1 & Following - .htaccess files are still a little mysterious to me...

Comment: Yeah I never seem to get these right.  And it is really hard to get help with this stuff too. :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after many headaches this example worked:

RewriteRule ^outdoors/swift_bird.php http://www.comehike.com/outdoors/birds/bird.php?bird_id=1 [R,L]

The difference seems to be putting the [R,L] at the end of the line.  But I can't explain why.  Maybe someone else can.  I just know that after I added it, this redirect started working.

Comment: @cinqoTimo since you were curious about this, did you try it?  Did it work for you?